# error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the similar type

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have two packages: `infrastructure` and another where I use it. When I'm compiling the `infrastructure` package, everything is fine. However, when I attempt to use it, I encounter an error. For an unknown reason, it uses the `build` and `source` folders. By the way, I'm connecting it to another project through `npm link`.

```
../../infrastructure/source/global.ts:8:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'componentManager' must be of type 'ComponentManager', but here has type 'ComponentManager'.

    8         var componentManager : ComponentManager;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      ../../infrastructure/build/global.d.ts:6:9
        6     var componentManager: ComponentManager;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        'componentManager' was also declared here.
```

here is `tsconfig.json` of `infrastructure`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": false,
        "target": "es5",                          
        "module": "NodeNext",                   
        "lib": ["es6","DOM"],                     
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "build",    
        "rootDir": "source",     
        "strict": true,   
        "sourceMap": true,      
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "files": ["source/index.ts"],
    "include": ["source/index.ts"]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "infrastructure",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "npx nodemon",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node build/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "guid-ts": "^1.1.2",
    "immutable": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "guid-ts": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the project where I was trying to import, there were paths like `from "infrastructure/source/..."`. Because of that, I had classes from source and also from the compiled version.